How was Hannah to serve God and be able to give up her first born, Samuel?
What personality characteristics did Hannah have to be able to give her first born up to the Lord?

1 Sam 1:11 - And she made a vow, pleading, “O LORD of Hosts, if only
You will look upon the affliction of Your maidservant and remember me,
not forgetting Your maidservant but giving her a son, then I will
dedicate him to the LORD all the days of his life, and no razor shall
ever come over his head.”


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour to better understand how this site is different.

Hnnah was desperate for a child and was will to take ANY steps to get one.

Being a childless woman might have been enough. My own mother claimed to have made a less detailed prayer of that kind when she thought she might be expecting me. (And here I am. Thanks. mum.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community bot - the highly emotional tension between a mother's love for her precious baby, and a sacrificial devotion to the LORD God, is a very real dilemma worth seeking an answer to!

Like Mary in the NT, Hannah believed that God, more than any man, was the father of her child. The couple could not conceive until Hannah desperately prayed at the tabernacle, where she received God's blessing through the priest, Eli. (1 Samuel 1:17)
How was she able to bring herself to  offer her son to the Temple? The answer is quite simple: She saw God as the child's father, and she was an honest woman, so she kept the vow she had made, as mentioned in the OP. No doubt this was not easy for her, but she had confidence that the boy would be well cared for, and she visited him several times a year (1 Samuel 2:19).
Indeed, Hannah was the opposite of downhearted in offering her son. She had gone from being a despised, childless woman - persecuted by her rival - to being the mother of a son destined for greatness through the Lord's anointing:
1 Samuel 2

“My heart exults in the Lord,
my horn is exalted by my God. I have swallowed up my enemies;
I rejoice in your victory. 2 There is no Holy One like the Lord;
there is no Rock like our God. 3 Speak boastfully no longer,
Do not let arrogance issue from your mouths. For an all-knowing God is the Lord,
a God who weighs actions...The Lord’s foes shall be shattered;
the Most High in heaven thunders;
the Lord judges the ends of the earth. May he give strength to his king,
and exalt the horn of his anointed!”

Personality characteristics that Hannah demonstrated in offering up her son included:

prophecy: Hannah was one of seven female prophets mentioned in the Talmud (Meg. 14a.)
hopefulness: a never-failing desire to fulfill God's blessing to be fruitful (Gen. 1:28)
faith: a belief that God was able to bring about a miracle of fertility for her
integrity: an absolute commitment to fulfill the vow she made and
a grateful heart when God performed the miracle she hoped for.


@DanFefferman.Excellent analysis and List of character qualities. Mother Mary must have thought so too, and patterned her Magnificat after Hannah's !

A Woman's DesperationThroughout the Bible a barren wife's desperation is often displayed. The angst of childlessness seemed to be a curse in society, as well as a personal failure. Hannah was a victim of this dilemma, and desperation drove her to make a vow.
This faith in the ability of God to perform miracles was one of Hannah's noble characteristics. What nature rendered impossible, the Creator God was able to perform.
Hannah had integrity and was not unfaithful to her promises; she did "lend Samuel to the LORD" (KJV) as promised...BUT she was not uncaring as a mother. She kept the boy child until he was "weaned." That could have been several years. So Samuel was not bereft of a mother's love in early childhood.
Hannah also had an enduring love for her child---even though Samuel was in the tutelage of Eli.  She brought Samuel gifts every year that she and her husband came to worship at the annual religious festivals. (2:19)
Hannah also had belief in the goodness of God. As is often repeated in holy pulpits: God is a debter to no man! He repays acts of kindness and sacrifice in a most gracious way. So, notice that Hannah was blessed with three more sons and two daughters! (1 Samuel 2:21)
The spiritual and motherly characteristic of Hannah are eloquently expressed in Hannah's magnificant. (2:1-10) It became an example for Mary, centuries later when Jesus was born! (Luke 1:46-56)
Hannah's life is not an example of an uncaring mother willing to do anything for her personal fulfilment.  But rather, an example of a close relationship and trust in her God that is quite exemplary for all women to emulate.
